# Proper use of generics in abstract java class?

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

**EDIT**: This question is not well worded, and the provided answer is correct in a literal sense but did not teach me how to attain what I needed. If you are struggling with the same problem, this is what finally helped me: [How to enforce child class behavior/methods when the return types of these methods depends on the child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570471/how-to-enforce-child-class-behavior-methods-when-the-return-types-of-these-metho)

I am trying to implement a basic matrix class from a boilerplate abstract class I wrote. There will be several implementations of this abstract class, each one using a different math library, which I will then test for speed.

Each implementation will hold its data in that library's native matrix data structure. I **think** this is a use case for generics. At this point I think I've read too many tutorials and watched too many videos, as I just can't seem to figure out all the right places to put the `T` Notation to make this work correctly.

So my question is twofold:

1. Have I misused or missed the point of generics?
2. If not, what is the correct syntax for their use?

I've read the docs plus about three different tutorials and still can't understand.

Here is what I've tried:

```
public abstract class BaseMatrix<T> {

    protected int[] shape;
    protected int nrows;
    protected int ncols;
    protected T data; // <--- Here is the generic data --->

    public BaseMatrix(int rows, int cols){
        this.nrows = rows;
        this.ncols = cols;
        this.shape = new int[]{nrows, ncols};
    }    

    public abstract BaseMatrix mmul(BaseMatrix other);
```

And here is my implementation:

```
public class ND4JDenseMatrix extends BaseMatrix{
    

    // private INDArray data;

    public ND4JDenseMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
        super(rows, cols);
        this.data = Nd4j.zeros(this.shape); <--- Here is the non-generic data --->
    }


    @Override
    public ND4JDenseMatrix mmul(ND4JDenseMatrix other) {
      ND4JDenseMatrix result = new ND4JDenseMatrix(nrows, ncols);
      result.data = data.mmul(other.data);
      return result;
    }
```

The error is: `Method does not override method from its superclass.`

Comment: Pay attention to the warning that you're getting on the line `extends BaseMatrix`.

Comment: Pretty sure `mmul()` should be returning `T` in the abstract class.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It is somewhat similar to the @Override warning: `Class 'ND4JDenseMatrix' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'mmul(BaseMatrix)' in 'BaseMatrix'`. I'm definitely not implementing the mmul abstract class correctly... but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper It should! And shouldn't! I think I see what you are saying! Let me try some stuff.

Comment: That's correct, but also you should `extends BaseMatrix<ND4JDenseMatrix>`. By the way, it appears that you're attempting the [tag:crtp], which unfortunately can't be exactly expressed in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> hold its data in that library's native matrix data structure. I think this is a use case for generics.

Generics serves to **link** things. You declared the type variable with `<T>`, and you've used it in, as far as your paste goes, exactly one place (a field, of type T). That's a red flag; generally, given that it links things, if you use it in only one place that's usually a bad sign.

Here's what I mean: Imagine you want to write a method that says: This method takes 2 parameters and returns something. This code doesn't particularly care what you toss in here, but, the parameters must be the same type and I return something of that type too. You want to *link* the type of the parameter, the type of the other parameter, and the return type together.

**That** is what generics is for.

It may apply here, if we twist our minds a bit: You want to link the type of the `data` field to a notion that some specific implementation of BaseMatrix can only operate on some specific type, e.g. ND4JMatrix.

However, mostly, no, this doesn't strike me as proper use of generics. You can avoid it altogether quite easily: Just.. stop having that `private T data;` field. What good is it doing you here? You have **no idea** what type that is, you don't even know if it is serializable. You know nothing about it, and the compiler confirms this: There is absolutely not one iota you can do with that object, except things you can do to all objects which are generally quite uninteresting. You can call `.toString()` on it, synchronize on it, maybe invoke `.hashCode()`, that's about it.

Why not just ditch that field? The implementation can make the field, no need for it to be in base!

```
public class ND4JDense extends BaseMatrix {
    private ND4JMatrix data; // why not like this?
}
```

(This code assumes 'ND4JMatrix' is the proper data type you desire here, a thing that can is the internal representation for the data in the ND4J impl).

However, if you must, yeah, you can use generics here. You've type-varred BaseMatrix, and that means **all usages of BaseMatrix must be parameterized**. That's the part you messed up in your code. If we go with your plan of a type-parameterized BaseMatrix class and a field of type T, the right code is:

```
public class ND4JDense extends BaseMatrix<ND4JMatrix> {
   ...
}
```

I wouldn't, however, do it this way (I'd go with having the impl have the field, much simpler, no need to bother anybody with the generics). Unless, of course, you *DO* have an actual need for that field and it IS part of BaseMatrix's API. For example, if you want this:

```
public class BaseMatrix<T> {
    public T getData() { return data; }
}
```

then it starts to make more sense. With that, you can write the following and it'll all compile and work great:

```
public class ND4JDense extends BaseMatrix<ND4JMatrix> {
    ...
    // no need to write a getData method here at all!
    ...
}

ND4JDense dense = new ND4JDense();
ND4JMatrix matrix = dense.getData();
```

But, clearly, this makes no sense if you intend for the ND4JMatrix to remain an implementation detail that users of the BaseMatrix API should probably not be touching.

---

EDIT: You changed the question on me, later. Now you want the `mmul` method to take 'self' as argument, effectively: You want the same type to be passed in.

You can sort of do that but it is a little tricky. You need the self-ref generics hack. It looks like this:

```
public class BaseMatrix<T extends BaseMatrix<T>> {
   public abstract T mmul(T other);
}
```

In practice the only valid value for T is your own class, or at least, that is the intent. This works fine:

```
public class ND4JDenseMatrix extends BaseMatrix<ND4JDenseMatrix> {
    public ND4JDenseMatrix mmul(ND4JDenseMatrix other) {
      .. impl here ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I don't think I'd ever want to have a getter for the `data` variable since then that would expose the underlying library and defeat the purpose of abstracting it away, right?

Comment: Also, I see that your answer is getting a lot of upvotes, but taking your advice has not removed the error stated in the question. Specifically something about my `mmul` implementation is off. When I make the signature accept the child class as an argument, the warning occurs. When I change the argument back to a parent class object it disappears... But the parent class doesn't know anything about ND4J library... I'm very, very confused. I'm not sure if I should ask another question and just accept yours? I think it answers what I asked, but not what I intended to ask...

Comment: _but taking your advice has not removed the error stated in the question_ Given that my advice is to completely remove the generics, I find that particularly hard to believe. If you want to ignore that advice, well, you changed the question on me. I've added an addendum to the answer that explains how to move forward. The reason it won't work in your basic question is that you've defined any impl of BaseMatrix to be capable of receiving the `mmul` message with _any_ instance of BaseMatrix, not just 'instances of self'.

Comment: I didn't mean to change the code in a way that changed the question. However, the error remains when all generics are gone. As I stated, you answered the question I asked and I accepted it, even if it wasn't the end of my problems. I am writing a new question now and will provide a link if you care to see how it doesn't work even when I removed all generics as in your last code block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570471/how-to-enforce-child-class-behavior-methods-when-the-return-types-of-these-metho

Comment: I updated this answer __2 days__ ago with the right answer to your new question. I'm a bit insulted you decided to just not read it and ask another question instead. (Compare my edit to the answer you accepted on the new question. Practically identical).

Comment: You got your green checkmark, but I didn't understand your answer. I think it was apparent what I was trying to achieve BEFORE my edit, and your answer was too convoluted and didn't help. You had already confused me so much that my brain was too overloaded to figure out what you were trying to say with your edit. Maybe I'm stupid,  but I don't think your answer was a good one for the reasons stated above. However, I still gave it to you, and I feel that should satisfy you. Perhaps your answer will help someone smarter than me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you have two issues in your code:

1. You're not actually overriding the method of the superclass. What you have created is an overload of method `mmul`. To correctly override the method, the method signature must match, in particular the input parameter must be the same. It's ok to have a subtype of the return type, as Java support `covariant`. If you instead put one of its subclass, that is overloading. Hope you get the difference. So the correct signature can be the following:

   public BaseMatrix mmul(BaseMatrix other) {
   ...
   }
2. You have not specified the type `T`, so the compiler cannot know that by assumption is a subtype of `BaseMatrix`. it can be any type, even `Object` for example, so you are going to get "method not found" compilation error.