# How to enforce child class behavior/methods when the return types of these methods depends on the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

#### What I want to achieve:

I am trying to write an abstract class that is a blueprint for the types of data and behaviors that all of its children should have. However, the return types of these enforced methods will depend on the child class itself.

#### My attempt:

I have been informed in the comments to one of my many closed questions that what I am doing here is overloading my parents methods instead of overriding them. I understand this is because I changed the method signature, and `@Override` requires that the signature be identical, but the implementation can be different.

```
public abstract class BaseMatrix {

    protected int[] shape;
    protected int nrows;
    protected int ncols;

    public BaseMatrix(int rows, int cols){
        this.nrows = rows;
        this.ncols = cols;
        this.shape = new int[]{nrows, ncols};
    }

    // ** here is the method I want to implement/override **
    public abstract BaseMatrix mmul(BaseMatrix other);
```

I initially tried to use generics to overcome the problem but discovered I don't understand them well enough to implement a solution that way. So instead I took the advice found in two similary questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638886/3696204 and [Proper use of generics in abstract java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67541507/proper-use-of-generics-in-abstract-java-class/67541618#67541618)

```
public class ND4JDenseMatrix extends BaseMatrix{

    private INDArray data;

    public ND4JDenseMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
        super(rows, cols);
        this.data = Nd4j.zeros(this.shape);
    }

    // ** Here is my attempt at implementing the abstract method. **
    @Override
    public ND4JDenseMatrix mmul(ND4JDenseMatrix other) {
        INDArray product = this.data.mmul(other.data);
        ND4JDenseMatrix result =  new ND4JDenseMatrix(this.nrows, this.ncols);
        result.setData(product);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This results in a warning at the `@Override`:

`Method does not override method from its superclass`

However, if I use the identical method signature in the child class:

```
public class ND4JDenseMatrix extends BaseMatrix{
    public BaseMatrix mmul(BaseMatrix other) { ...implementation...}
}
```

Then Someone could pass ANY child of the `BaseMatrix` class `mmul()`, which would almost certainly break.

#### My Question

Given that I know that I am overloading and not overriding, how can I achieve the functionality described in the first section of my question that enforces the type being passed to the child class methods?

Comment: A `ND4JDenseMatrix` *is a* `BaseMatrix`, so you can leave the method signature as `public BaseMatrix mmul(BaseMatrix)` and still pass in and return a `ND4JDenseMatrix`.

Comment: @azurefrog But won't that allow users to pass in any child of the `BaseMatrix` class? Because if that happened, the results are probably going to fail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the inheritance at subject is a technical one and not to be used with polymorphism in mind (since the return value is not polymorphic of the `BaseMatrix` type), it is possible using generics.

```
public abstract class BaseMatrix<T extends BaseMatrix<T>> {
    protected int[] shape;
    protected int nrows;
    protected int ncols;

    public BaseMatrix(int rows, int cols){
        this.nrows = rows;
        this.ncols = cols;
        this.shape = new int[]{nrows, ncols};
    }

    public abstract T mmul(T other);
}

public class ND4JDenseMatrix extends BaseMatrix<ND4JDenseMatrix> {

    private INDArray data;

    public ND4JDenseMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
        super(rows, cols);
        this.data = Nd4j.zeros(this.shape);
    }

    @Override
    public ND4JDenseMatrix mmul(ND4JDenseMatrix other) {
        INDArray product = this.data.mmul(other.data);
        ND4JDenseMatrix result =  new ND4JDenseMatrix(this.nrows, this.ncols);
        result.setData(product);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat I see what you are saying, and you might be right. But is that worse than the problem you suggested in your answer? It seems like I have to choose one problem and live with it...

Comment: @GhostCat indeed, I assume that the inheritance here is a technical one (code reuse) and not real polymorphism. I will add it to the answer

Comment: Yes, code re-use is the name of the game. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
@Override
public ND4JDenseMatrix mmul(ND4JDenseMatrix other) {
```

Java overriding is *co-variant* for [return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type).

This means:

- you can **narrow** the return type (which you do here: ND4JDenseMatrix is more specific than BaseMatrix)
- but you can NOT **narrow** parameters!

And that is what you are doing here: you restrict your method to a parameter type that is **more** specific than the one in the base class.

In other words, it can only work like this:

```
@Override
public ND4JDenseMatrix mmul(BaseMatrix other) {
```

That is real problem here. You see, a **caller** of that method is told that it can pass in *anything* that is a BaseMatrix. But you want to restrict it to a more specific subtype of BaseMatrix.